# Codeigniter 3 Joins in One table

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to display the User Name Who created, but in the database the create name is in the form of int which is the id of the author.

How can I display the id to be the real name by using Join in one table.
Or if there is another way I will try.

For the table as below

```
+----+--------------+-------------+
| Id | user_create  |     name    |
+----+--------------+-------------+
|  1 |         Null |       Admin |
|  2 |           1  |        User |
+----+--------------+-------------+
```

and I want to display it like this

**Detail User**

Name        : User

User Create : Admin

Answer (score 1):

if I remember correctly the CI 3 syntax

```
$this->db
   ->select(['t1.name', 't2.name user_create']) 
   ->join('thetable t2', 't2.user_create = t1.id', 'left')
   ->get('thetable t1');
```

Comment: This is a join for different tables, but I want to join in one table

Comment: It's  the same table with different alias